# Splitting Excel into multiple rows by delimiter (;) using Power Automate

Tags: excel, power-automate

I am rather new to Power Automate, and despite my best research efforts (including quite a bit of work with ChatGPT), I can't seem to find a solution for my problem. I am trying to set up a Power Automate flow to split an Excel row into multiple rows by delimiter. I know this is easy to do in Power Query/on Excel itself, but I'm really stuck here.

I made a test file to work through this issue, and it looks like this:

| Column A | Test |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Cat;Dog;Mouse |
| Name 2 | Deer;Elk;Moose |

Here is what I want the final result to look like:

| Column A | Test |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Cat |
| Name 1 | Dog |
| Name 1 | Mouse |
| Name 2 | Deer |
| Name 2 | Elk |
| Name 2 | Moose |

This is the current flow I have in Power Automate:

[Full Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCJue.png)

1. Manually trigger a flow

[2. Initialize Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TXR5.png)

[3. List rows present in a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZmOC.png)

[4. Apply to each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ8sC.png)
> body/value = (outputs('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['body/value']

[4.1 Compose (Nested within above "Apply to each")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPyDy.png)
> Inputs: split(items('Apply_to_each')?['Test'], ';')

[4.2 Apply to each 1 (Nested within above "Apply to each", after "Compose")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMEjl.png) 
> Select An Output From Previous Steps: outputs('Compose')

[4.2.1 Add a row into a table (Nested within "Apply to each 1")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1pWl.png)
> Selected the file and specific table from my OneDrive, no advanced parameters set.

According to ChatGPT, I should be seeing more options for 4.2.1. I am not. Currently, the flow runs, but all it does it create blank rows in my table. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it! :)

Comment: You need to show us a screenshot of your flow. We can’t possibly tell you where you’re go wrong when you haven’t even shown us how you’re filling the table.

Comment: Just to add, this would be inefficient to do this like you have in PowerAutomate. I would suggest looking at OfficeScript to do this and then have PowerAutomate call that script on the needed file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70111620/split-column-into-rows-using-excel-office-script to get you going.

Comment: I added photos! And I had thought about going with a script. Problem is that I have to turn off autosave to make the doc macro-enabled, and company policy is to keep autosave on whenever possible.